# How am I able to get my program to convert the incrementing numbers into a string so the jpg files are able to open in order in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import os
frame = Tk()
frame.geometry('300x350+200+300')


count = 0
def pic():
    global count
    count1 = count + 1#count variable which equals the name of the jpg file
    count = str(count1)#this variable converts it into string so the program opens the file
    os.startfile("D:\\spanishpics\\"+ count + ".jpg")


title = Label(text ="spanish pictures").pack()
but = Button(command  = pic, height = 3, width = 20, bg = 'light blue').pack()
frame.mainloop()
```

The program doesn't convert the a string after the number 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning a string to `count` in line 3 of pic:

```
count = str(count1)
```

This is changing the `count` defined outside of `pic`. So the first time, it works because it is adding `1` to `count` (which is `0`), but the second time, `count` is equal to `"1"` (a string instead of an `int`). The second time `pic` gets called, it's trying to add `"1" + 1`, which will raise an error because you have to convert `count` back into an `int`.

Use

```
count1 = int(count) + 1
```

to increment `count` correctly to 2, then 3, and so on each time `pic` is called.